# Do I need a close or similar statement to upload a second file (in the same run session) to a web site?

Tags: vb.net

I have two textboxes on a windows form program to enter filenames for uploading files to my web site, one for PDF files and one for HTML files and a button for each for the necessary events. Each one works fine if I upload one file, but I can't do a second file without closing the project and starting again.

I enter a PDF filename and click on the pdf upload button...it works fine but when I enter a second file in the HTML textbox and click on the html upload button nothing happens, but if I close the program and start again entering a HTML file into the Html text box and click on the html button it works fine. I would like to be able to enter one each PDF and HTML file and click on the buttons and have both files uploaded.

```
Private Sub BtnUploadPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUploadPDF.Click
    Dim myuploadfilePDF As String = TxtInputBoxPDF.Text
    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("C:\...\" & myuploadfilePDF,
       New Uri("ftp://.../" & myuploadfilePDF), "username", "password")
End Sub

Private Sub BtnUploadHTML_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUploadHTML.Click
    Dim myuploadfileHTML As String = TxtInputBoxHTML.Text
    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("C:\...\" & myuploadfileHTML,
       New Uri("ftp://.../" & myuploadfileHTML), "username", "password")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Try this format: `My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(sourceFileName ,address ,networkCredentials ,showUI ,connectionTimeout ,onUserCancel)`. Where you specify you credentials as NetworkCredentials and `showUI` is set to `True`. See whether the upload completes.

Comment: I added the showUI (true) and connectionTimeout (30000) 30seconds. I did not add onUserCancel because files are very small and load very fast once the server is connected.  The uploads are working...thanks for your tip.